# xPath is wrong given by the Browser or HTMLAgilityPack cannot use xPath?

Tags: c#, html, xpath, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to get all languages from Google Translate. When I Open Developer Tools and click one of the language when all languages are popped (when arrow clicked), It gives `//*[@id=':7']/div/text()` for Arabic, but it returns null when I try to get node:

```
 async Task AddLanguages()
    {
        try
        {
            // //*[@id=":6"]/div/text()
            HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument();
            document.LoadHtml(html);
            for (int i = 6; i <= 9; i++)
            {
                //*[@id=":6"]/div/text()            //*[@id=":6"]/div/div
                Debug.WriteLine(i);
                var element = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id=':7']/div/text()");
                Trace.WriteLine(element == null, "Element is null");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            this.ShowMessageAsync("Hata!", "Dilleri yüklerken hata ortaya çıktı.");
        }
    }
```

`Element is null: True` outputs all the times ( I was trying to use for loop to loop through languages but, it doesnt even work for single one!)

Comment: I don't think it is legal to have an id that starts with ":" so I can't see how this would work. Do you have the url/html you are trying to scrape?

Comment: @Stuart As i said, its Google Translate, and if you popup all languages, and right click arabic then right click --> copy --> xPath, it gives that and it has a dot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your xpath is wrong. You can try something like:

```
        string Url = "https://translate.google.com/";
        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(Url);
        var arabic = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div").FirstOrDefault(_ => _.ChildNodes.Any(node => node.Name.Equals("#text") && node.InnerText.Equals("Arabic")));
```

Comment: I will try it as soon as possible.

Comment: The id(s) of those elements are generated dynamically I believe so I think we can't trust them.

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't comment yet...Have you tried clicking on the dropdwon first before looking for the elements?
Clicking on //*[@id='gt-sl-gms'] or it's inner div would make the elements visible..
That should work..

Anyway, I can't make $x work for the console in google chrome. I'm getting an Uncaught Type Error currently. Not sure if that has to do with anything..

Edit: Oh wait i think I know your problem..upon closer inspection of the element, it seems that the element (div) has another div before the text. so try /*[@id=':7']/div/text()[2]

Comment: IDropdown Items may be hidden,but they still exist. I fhink thats not the problem.

Comment: I know it does..but the question is have you tried it? In Robot Framework, using the Selenium2Library, I believe that when you get this element without it being visible it would return nothing. So it might be the same thing here?

Comment: Oh wait i think I know your problem..upon closer inspection of the element, it seems that the element (div) has another div before the text. so try /*[@id=':7']/div/text()[2]